# SpeechRecognitionServer not found in Mavericks with applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, voice-recognition, speech

I am trying to use an applescript to get speech input from a user and then perform and action. However, the code i'm using was made for osx lion. When I put it into applescript editor, the editor gives me a pop-up asking where "speechrecognitionserver" is. How do i find it? I'm on OSX mavericks right now.

the code is here:
http://media.pragprog.com/titles/mrhome/code/GivingYourHomeAVoice/osx-voice-automation.scpt

Answer (score 4):

Right at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognitionServer.app
```

When it asks, click Browse and type <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then paste the path in.

With that specific script there are a few errors (you'll need to get rid of the `Â`s with find and replace, and there is a comment after a line continuation character in `else if voiceResponse is "pause music" or Â¬   -- <callout id="code.osx-voice-automation.scpt.miscmusic"/>`). After doing that I got it to run on my machine.

Oh, and if you're wondering *how* I found it - `mdfind` is Spotlight's Terminal interface, and it shows hidden files, so when I ran `mdfind SpeechRecognitionServer` it came up with the path.

Final script (this isn't going to fix your original problem):

```
with timeout of 2629743 seconds
    set exitApp to "no"
    repeat while exitApp is "no"
        tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer" -- 
            activate
            try
                set voiceResponse to listen for {"light on", "light off", ¬
                    "unlock door", "play music", "pause music", ¬
                    "unpause music", "stop music", "next track", ¬
                    "raise volume", "lower volume", ¬
                    "previous track", "check email", "time", "make a call", ¬
                    "hang up", "quit app"} giving up after 2629743
            on error -- time out
                return
            end try
        end tell

        if voiceResponse is "light on" then -- 
            -- open URL to turn on Light Switch  
            open location "http://192.168.1.100:3344/command/on"
            say "The light is now on."

        else if voiceResponse is "light off" then
            -- open URL to turn off Light Switch
            open location "http://192.168.1.100:3344/command/off"
            say "The light is now off."

        else if voiceResponse is "unlock door" then
            -- open URL to unlock Android Door Lock
            open location "http://192.168.1.230:8000"
            say "Unlocking the door."

        else if voiceResponse is "play music" then -- 
            tell application "iTunes"
                set musicList to {"Cancel"} as list
                set myList to (get artist of every track ¬
                    of playlist 1) as list
                repeat with myItem in myList
                    if musicList does not contain myItem then
                        set musicList to musicList & myItem
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell

            say "Which artist would you like to listen to?"
            tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
                set theArtistListing to ¬
                    (listen for musicList with prompt musicList)
            end tell
            if theArtistListing is not "Cancel" then
                say "Which of " & theArtistListing & ¬
                    "'s albums would you like to listen to?"
                tell application "iTunes"
                    tell source "Library"
                        tell library playlist 1
                            set uniqueAlbumList to {}
                            set albumList to album of tracks ¬
                                where artist is equal to theArtistListing

                            repeat until albumList = {}
                                if uniqueAlbumList does not contain ¬
                                    (first item of albumList) then
                                    copy (first item of albumList) to end of ¬
                                        uniqueAlbumList
                                end if
                                set albumList to rest of albumList
                            end repeat

                            set theUniqueAlbumList to {"Cancel"} & uniqueAlbumList
                            tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
                                set theAlbum to (listen for the theUniqueAlbumList ¬
                                    with prompt theUniqueAlbumList)
                            end tell
                        end tell
                        if theAlbum is not "Cancel" then
                            if not ((name of playlists) contains "Current Album") then
                                set theAlbumPlaylist to ¬
                                    make new playlist with properties {name:"Current Album"}
                            else
                                set theAlbumPlaylist to playlist "Current Album"
                                delete every track of theAlbumPlaylist
                            end if
                            tell library playlist 1 to duplicate ¬
                                (every track whose album is theAlbum) to theAlbumPlaylist
                            play theAlbumPlaylist
                        else
                            say "Canceling music selection"
                        end if
                    end tell
                end tell
            else
                say "Canceling music selection"
            end if

        else if voiceResponse is "pause music" or ¬
            voiceResponse is "unpause music" then
            tell application "iTunes"
                playpause
            end tell

        else if voiceResponse is "stop music" then
            tell application "iTunes"
                stop
            end tell

        else if voiceResponse is "next track" then
            tell application "iTunes"
                next track
            end tell

        else if voiceResponse is "previous track" then
            tell application "iTunes"
                previous track
            end tell

            -- Raise and lower volume routines courtesy of HexMonkey's post:  
            -- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=144749  
        else if voiceResponse is "raise volume" then --       
            set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
            set scaledVolume to round (currentVolume / (100 / 16))
            set scaledVolume to scaledVolume + 1
            if (scaledVolume > 16) then
                set scaledVolume to 16
            end if
            set newVolume to round (scaledVolume / 16 * 100)
            set volume output volume newVolume
        else if voiceResponse is "lower volume" then
            set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
            set scaledVolume to round (currentVolume / (100 / 16))
            set scaledVolume to scaledVolume - 1
            if (scaledVolume 
            tell application "Mail"
                activate
                check for new mail
                set unreadEmailCount to unread count in inbox
                if unreadEmailCount is equal to 0 then
                    say "You have no unread messages in your Inbox."
                else if unreadEmailCount is equal to 1 then
                    say "You have 1 unread message in your Inbox."
                else
                    say "You have " & unreadEmailCount & ¬
                        " unread messages in your Inbox."
                end if
                if unreadEmailCount is greater than 0 then
                    say "Would you like me to read your unread email to you?"
                    tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
                        activate
                        set voiceResponse to listen for {"yes", "no"} ¬
                            giving up after 1 * minutes
                    end tell
                    if voiceResponse is "yes" then
                        set allMessages to every message in inbox
                        repeat with aMessage in allMessages
                            if read status of aMessage is false then
                                set theSender to sender of aMessage
                                set {savedDelimiters, AppleScript's text item delimiters} ¬
                                    to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "
            set current_time to (time string of (current date))
            set {savedDelimiters, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
                {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ":"}
            set hours to first text item of current_time
            set minutes to the second text item of current_time
            set AMPM to third text item of current_time
            set AMPM to text 3 thru 5 of AMPM
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedDelimiters
            say "The time is " & hours & " " & minutes & AMPM
            --else if voiceResponse is "make a call" then    
            --  tell application "Skype"
            -- -- A Skype API Security dialog will pop up first 
            -- -- time accessing Skype with this script.
            -- -- Select "Allow this application to use Skype" for ¬
            -- -- uninterrupted Skype API access.
            --    activate
            --   -- replace echo123 Skype Call Testing Service ID with ¬
            --   -- phone number or your contact's Skype ID
            --      send command "CALL echo123" script name ¬
            --      "Place Skype Call"
            --    end tell
            --  else if voiceResponse is "hang up" then
            --    tell application "Skype"
            --      quit
            --  end tell
        else if voiceResponse is "quit app" then -- 
            set exitApp to "yes"
            say "Listening deactivated. Exiting application."
            delay 1
            do shell script "killall SpeechRecognitionServer"
        end if
    end repeat
end timeout
```

Comment: Now that is a good answer specific the Terminal find.

Comment: Could you republish the modified script that you made to work please.

Comment: @Buscar웃: Edited in.

Comment: One of your lines is `if (scaledVolume `, which is clearly not correct. What is that meant to be?